# Rounding corner causes top edge to blur

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a UIButton subclass that I am rounding the corners of. Using either the usual `cornerRadius` property on its layer, or creating a rounded mask and applying that to the layer, I always get the effect shown in the image below (blown up so you can see it clearly). The top pixel is slightly transparent, making the edge look soft. If I remove the rounded corners, the edge goes back to solid (like the bottom edge in the image), so I know it's not just trying to draw the view between pixels.

Any ideas?

[image: Corner]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be sure that the frame and the mask are fully composed of integers not floats, in case use floor or ceil to get the closest integer rounding by low or top.
 With frames CGRectIntegral is very helpful.
 Floats values automatically create a sort of antialiasing while rendering on screen.

Comment: This is correct, although i think he just might have a broken origin on the button's frame (20.5 for example).

Comment: This was mostly correct. I knew that the frame of my button was composed of integers. However, it was contained within a table view cell whose height was *not* composed of integers. Fixing the cell height fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is anti-aliasing (on by default) to make the edges look smooth. This is the only way to make rounded corners look smooth and not stair stepped. If you want rough edges, set the `allowsEdgeAntialiasing` and `edgeAntialiasingMask`